# Column sum in mutate function in R

Tags: r

I have a iris where i need to divide each by the sum of respective columns . So i am thinking to use mutate so all operation happens at once. But I am getting below errow

```
iris1 <- head(iris[1:4])
iris1 %>% mutate(across(c(1:4), ~.-colSums(.)))
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
ℹ Input `..1` is `across(c(1:4), ~. - colSums(.))`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Expected out (Since 29.7 is the sum of 1 column. Similar for other columns)

```
       Sepal.Length         Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1/29.7             3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9/29.7             3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7/29.7             3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6/29.7             3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0/29.7             3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4/29.7             3.9          1.7         0.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close.
Is this what you want?

```
head(iris[1:4]) %>% summarise(across(.cols = c(1:4), .fns = function(x) {x/sum(x)}))
```

Output:

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    0.1717172   0.1724138    0.1609195   0.1428571
2    0.1649832   0.1477833    0.1609195   0.1428571
3    0.1582492   0.1576355    0.1494253   0.1428571
4    0.1548822   0.1527094    0.1724138   0.1428571
5    0.1683502   0.1773399    0.1609195   0.1428571
6    0.1818182   0.1921182    0.1954023   0.2857143
```

Comment: @user11740857 If think you get an error because of the actual output of `colSums(head(iris[1:4]))`. Maybe comparing `colSums(head(iris[1:4]))` and `head(iris[1:4]) %>% summarise(across(.cols = c(1:4), .fns = function(x) {sum(x)}))` shows why your code produced an error

Answer (score 0):

A more concise solution:

```
iris1 %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~./sum(.)))
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    0.1717172   0.1724138    0.1609195   0.1428571
2    0.1649832   0.1477833    0.1609195   0.1428571
3    0.1582492   0.1576355    0.1494253   0.1428571
4    0.1548822   0.1527094    0.1724138   0.1428571
5    0.1683502   0.1773399    0.1609195   0.1428571
6    0.1818182   0.1921182    0.1954023   0.2857143
```

Answer (score 0):

**base**

```
iris1/sapply(iris1, sum)

  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    0.1717172   0.4022989   0.04713805 0.022988506
2    0.2413793   2.1428571   0.06896552 0.142857143
3    0.5402299   0.1077441   0.14942529 0.006734007
4    3.2857143   0.1527094   1.07142857 0.009852217
5    0.1683502   0.4137931   0.04713805 0.022988506
6    0.2660099   2.7857143   0.08374384 0.285714286
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple base R option is `prop.table`

```
> list2DF(Map(prop.table, iris1))
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    0.1717172   0.1724138    0.1609195   0.1428571
2    0.1649832   0.1477833    0.1609195   0.1428571
3    0.1582492   0.1576355    0.1494253   0.1428571
4    0.1548822   0.1527094    0.1724138   0.1428571
5    0.1683502   0.1773399    0.1609195   0.1428571
6    0.1818182   0.1921182    0.1954023   0.2857143
```

or `mutate_all`

```
> iris1 %>%
+   mutate_all(prop.table)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1    0.1717172   0.1724138    0.1609195   0.1428571
2    0.1649832   0.1477833    0.1609195   0.1428571
3    0.1582492   0.1576355    0.1494253   0.1428571
4    0.1548822   0.1527094    0.1724138   0.1428571
5    0.1683502   0.1773399    0.1609195   0.1428571
6    0.1818182   0.1921182    0.1954023   0.2857143
```